# How to include selected date to event url in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add selected date to event url in fullcalendar listDay view. I want each selected day to have the date include in the event url.

This is what i need:

```
.......
events: [
        {
          title: 'event 1',
          url: 'example.com/test?date='{selected date here}',
          start: '2020-05-01',
          end: '2020-05-31'
        },
        {
          title: 'event 2',
          url: 'example.com/test?date='{selected date here}',
          start: '2020-05-01',
          end: '2020-05-31'
        }
        .....
```

So what i want to achieve is:
1. if i select 2020-05-01, i want the event url to be: 
`url: 'example.com/test?date='2020-05-01'`, and if i select 2020-05-30, the url will change to
`url: 'example.com/test?date='2020-05-30'`.

I tried `url: 'example.com/test?date='+ date.toISOString()` but it is giving me current date in all the days i selected. I tried also `url: 'example.com/test?date='+ moment(date).format()`. And still it is the same.

2. So when 2020-05-01 is selected, the code will look like this:

```
.......
events: [
        {
          title: 'event 1',
          url: 'example.com/test?date='2020-05-01',
          start: '2020-05-01',
          end: '2020-05-31'
        },
        {
          title: 'event 2',
          url: 'example.com/test?date='2020-05-01',
          start: '2020-05-01',
          end: '2020-05-31'
        }
        .....
```

Also when 2020-05-30 is selected, the code will look like this:

```
.......
events: [
        {
          title: 'event 1',
          url: 'example.com/test?date='2020-05-30',
          start: '2020-05-01',
          end: '2020-05-31'
        },
        {
          title: 'event 2',
          url: 'example.com/test?date='2020-05-30',
          start: '2020-05-01',
          end: '2020-05-31'
        }
        .....
```

Thanks in advance.

This is the complete code i'm using:

```
<script>

      $(document).ready(function() {
       var date = new Date(),
       d = date.getDate(),
       m = date.getMonth(),
       y = date.getFullYear();
       var curdate = new Date('Y-m-d');
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
          },
          views: {
        listDay: { buttonText: 'list day' },
        listWeek: { buttonText: 'list week' }
      },
          defaultView: 'listDay',
          defaultDate: console.log(curdate),
          navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
          editable: true,
          eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
          events: [
        {
          title: 'Event 1',
          url: 'example.com/test?date=selected date',
          start: '2020-05-01',
          end: '2020-05-31'
        },
        {
          title: 'Event 2',
          url: 'example.com/test2?date=selected date',
          start: '2020-05-01',
          end: '2020-05-31'
        },
        {
          title: 'Event 3',
          url: 'example.com/test3?date=selected date',
          start: '2020-05-01',
          end: '2020-05-31'
        },
        {
          title: 'Event 4',
          url: 'example.com/test4?date=selected date',
          start: '2020-05-01',
          end: '2020-05-30'
        },
        {
          title: 'Event 5',
          url: 'example.com/test5?date=selected date',
          start: '2020-05-01',
          end: '2020-06-01'
        }
      ]
    });

       $(".btn").append(
       '<div class="input-group datetimepicker"><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" style="padding: 0;width: 0;border: none;margin: 0;"></div>');

        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonText: '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>',
        inline: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var d = new Date(dateText);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      #calendar {
        max-width: 100%;
        /*max-width: 900px;*/
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .hoverEffect {
        font-size: 29px;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 30px 55px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
      .ui-datepicker-trigger{border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
      background: transparent;
        border: none;
        margin: 0!important;
        padding: 0!important;
        height: 30px!important;}
      .ui-datepicker-trigger .input-group-addon:last-child {
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    }
    .fc-basicDay-button{border-radius:0;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<span style="float:right" class="btn"></span>
<div id='calendar'></div>
    </body>
```

So i want any selected date to be included in the event url. For example when 2020-05-01 is selected on the calendar, the url will be `url: 'example.com/test?date=2020-05-01'` and when 2020-05-30 is selected, the url will be `url: 'example.com/test?date=2020-05-30'`

Comment: How are you generating the event data? Client side or server side? And using what language?

Comment: Please show your code where you retrieve the selected date.

Comment: @ADyson, for now i am using client side

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const d = new Date('2020-05-28')
const year = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(d)
const month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: '2-digit' }).format(d)
const day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(d)

console.log(`${year}-${month}-${day}`)
```

Comment: thanks but i don't know to implement this. I want to give the code for better understanding.

Comment: Do you want to get a string like this '2020-05-28' from var d = new Date(dateText) ? And can you give example of dateText?

Comment: Thanks. Yes i want to get a string like this '2020-05-28' from var d = new Date(dateText). I've updated the whole code i am using

Answer (score 0):

Looking closely at your event data, it seems you have got multi-day events, and you want to set the URL link dynamically when the user clicks on the part of an event which is within a particular day, and pass that specific date on the URL's querystring.

Unfortunately fullCalendar doesn't support this. When you click on an event, fullCalendar will inform you which event has been clicked on, but not which part of the event - e.g. in a multi-day you cannot tell if your click occurred over one day or a different day.

Depending what your reason for doing this is, there may be another way to solve your overall problem, but it would require more information about the context of your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. What i really want to achieve is: i want the same multi-day events for one month. For example: i have five church prayers (as events) everyday for 30 days. (Prayer 1, Prayer 2, Prayer 3, Prayer 4, Prayer 5) . Each day has its own Prayer 1, Prayer 2, Prayer 3, Prayer 4, Prayer 5. So i want to link each day to its own prayer. 01-05-2020 (Prayer 1, Prayer 2, Prayer 3, Prayer 4, Prayer 5), 02-05-2020 (Prayer 1, Prayer 2, Prayer 3, Prayer 4, Prayer 5). So the url will look like: example.com/prayer?date='01-05-2020'.

Comment: I see. I think unfortunately you will need to generate a separate event for each day in order to achieve that, rather than having multi-day events. I would suggest using some javascript to generate the event data rather than hard-coding it, otherwise the job will become quite tedious.

Comment: Thanks. Please how can i use javascript to generate the event data

Comment: Same way you will generate any kind of array or object using JavaScript. Are you stuck on any particular aspect of the task?